# uneditable variable in attribute table?

Tags: qgis, editing, attribute-joins

*Shapefile A* was joined with a new *variable x* from *table C*. Then I saved *Shapefile A* under a new name *Shapefile B*. The joined field (*variable x*) appears in *Shapefile B* as a "native" variable (which was my aim).

I tried to edit *Shapefile B*. Editing is possible, however, I cannot edit *variable x* in *Shapefile B*. I do not really understand why and how I can make the respective variable editable again.

All of this takes place in QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a bit of trial and error:
in the properties dialogue go to "fields", select the respective attribute, click on "Text Edit".

Then choose "Text Edit" and check "editable". This works.